# Returning first_name and last_name in a dropdown

Tags: django

I have a dropdown of usernames, but I would like instead first_name + Last_name from the user model. I have been trying to return these in the model in various ways, any idea where I've gone wrong?

```
def __str__(self):
    # return self.assigned_to.first_name
    # return str(self.firstname)+ '-' +str(self.lastname)
    # return u'%s %s' % (assigned_to.first_name, self.last_name)
    # return str(self.user.first_name)
    # return str(self.location_name)+ '.' +str(self.location_sub_name)
```

In my model:

```
assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, db_column='assigned_to', on_delete = models.PROTECT, related_name='assigned')
```

In my htmlform:

```
<div class="col col-md-4" style="color:white;">{{ form.assigned_to|add_class:"col-md-12"|append_attr:"placeholder:To"}}</div>
```

Comment: What's your `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`? Are you sure you have `first_name` and `last_name` populated?

Answer (score 0):

The `first_name` and `last_name` are attributes of the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User), given of course that you use that model, or a model that has a `first_name` and `last_name` attribute. You obtain these through `self.assigned_to.first_name` and `self.assigned_to.last_name`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        db_column='assigned_to',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='assigned'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(
            self.assigned_to.first_name,
            self.assigned_to.last_name
        )
```

As for your `Form`, you should specify the `attrs` into the form class itself.